# What Database Tables Contain Credit Card Information?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, database, orders

I have a Magento 1 database that I want to remove sensitive data from before I allow a consultant to connect to.

What tables/rows would I need to fill with dummy data? I have looked at my tables with `myPHPAdmin` and wasn't able to find one containing credit card information. I read somewhere that not all versions of Magento store credit card information.

Once I find the tables/columns to change, I assume that what I need is something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE transactions SET creditCardNum = "4111111111111111";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What tables/rows do I need to fill with dummy data?

---

1. "`sales_flat_quote_payment`"
2. "`sales_flat_order_payment`"

These two tables stores **credit card number** based on payment method config

---

**Note:**

Magento 1.8.1 : Your cc are stored here `sales_flat_order_payment`

---

If your payment method hold this,

```
protected $_canSaveCc   = false;
```

then credit card information **NOT** save into database.

> if you check `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc`, you will notice there is
>   a **flag** `$_canSaveCc` controls whether saving cc number, in saved
>   cc its true, in most other payment class, this flag is false.

**Dummy Query**

```
UPDATE sales_flat_quote_payment
SET cc_number = '4111111111111111'
WHERE id = 1;
```